# Get parent of a child element that has a certain class

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I have a nested menu like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Home
        <ul>
            <li>New</li>
            <li class="selected">Open</li>
            <li>Folder</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Another menu
        <ul>
            <li>submenu item 1</li>
            <li>submenu item 2</li>
            <li>submenu item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I'm trying to change the class of the first LI element (the one that contains Home), because it has a child element with a "selected" class. Is this possible using jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A faster and more precise method in catching targets.

```
$("li.selected").parents("#menu").addClass('foo');
```

Updated to add some class to first li child.

```
$("li.selected").parents("#menu").addClass('foo').find('li:first').addClass('bar');
```

I also reccomend reading the jQuery [Traversing](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing) documentation.

Comment: I'd like to add a CSS class to <li>Home. How should I do that?

Comment: This won't work if you have any `<li>`'s selected inside "Another menu"

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with this syntax.

```
$('.selected').parent().parent().addClass('foo').removeClass('bar');
```

Comment: Better to use .parents() selector

Comment: I don't see how it would be better exactly, could you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('li.selected').parent().closest('li').addClass('foo');
```

Edit: Sorry, only using closest will make it target itself.

or you can use:

```
$('li.selected').closest('li:not(".selected")').addClass('foo');
```